# Unsigned int with the floating point in c

Tags: c, int, unsigned

this goes like this in C

```
unsigned int i=-1;
print("%u",i);
```

the output is the two's complement of 1 all's well
but when i use

```
print("%u",-1*i);//displays the answer 1 i guess it uses i as signed int
print("%u",-2.2*i);//displays 2575826944
```

Any one please help

Comment: retype that first line as `print("%u",((unsigned)(-1))*i);` and you'll still get 1. The result really has nothing to do with c choosing to make the result signed. This is because that's simply how modular arithmetic works: (a-1)^2 mod a = a^2 - 2a + 1 mod a = 1 mod a

Answer (score 3):

`u` conversion specifier with `printf` requires an `unsigned int` argument but you are passing a `double` argument as `-2.2*i` is of type `double`. It invokes undefined behavior. Use `f` specifier to print a `double` argument.

Comment: Yup, he should try %f instead